# Iframe Link Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe on a page and there's a link inside the iframe. When user clicks on the link I want it to open in the current page (but not in the iframe), I want the current page to reload with the target of the link in the iframe.

How can I do that? I hope there is some javascript or jquery solution because I need to achieve this in my current project.

EDIT:

Or let's say there's a form in the iframe and when submitted I don't want the page to load in the iframe but to reload the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the anchor problem: To comply with XHTML Strict Doctype, you need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

```
$('.your_link').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.top.location.href = $(evt.target).attr('href');
});
```

But if Strict Doctypes don't matter, you can just use the `target` attribute

```
<a target="_top" href="...">...</a>
```

---

For the form problem: If you don't care about the Strict Doctype, then you can use the `target` attribute on the `form` element like so

```
<form target="_top" action="...">...</form>
```

But if you do care, then you'll have to get tricky. You will need to submit the form with AJAX. On a success, replace the html of `top` with the response.

Comment: Thank you. Will this also work with the second scenario (HTML form submits outside the iframe, or after the form is submitted, somehow redirect to a page outside the iframe).

Comment: if you want to open a new window use `target="_blank"` or `window.open()`

Answer (score 4):

Make the target attribute of the anchor "_top".

Therefore:

```
<a href="#" target="_top">Test</a>
```

this works in FF

**Edit** Concerning the new scenario of the form, I truly wouldn't know but for the anchor the above works.